# Need to rename index in 6.2.4 elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I have used _shrink api and shrinked my index from 5shards to 1 shard but with a different name and have deleted the old index. Now I want to rename the newly created index to the same old name, used _reindex api but that is creating the index with same old 5shards, but want to have it on single primary shard. Since am in 6.2.4 can't use _clone api.

Please advise. TIA

Abhishek

Comment: When you send the create index put command, also add the amount of shards in the setrings body.

Answer (score 0):

Add the amount of shards at index creation time:

```
PUT /my-index-000001
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
    }
  }
}
```

You can also add the mapping and other settings in this request.

See also:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

Comment: The one I am referring to is an existing index, hence this won't work. Although, have found a way to achieve this. The main purpose was to reduce the shard count as most of the indices are being written with 5 shards and 1 replica(make 10shards per index)

Just discovered, there is a way to change this default behavior using Index Templates.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-templates.html
This will get effect from next index creation (in my case from after midnight today), will check after that.